# Show arabic text in GUI

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode

Is there a way to show the following as Arabic text?
[image]

I used in my project frequently `char  *sql` and ANSI, what can I do ?

Comment: accept an answer, or if none of the answers covers the solution, write your own answer and accept it (this is needed so this question will not be listed as unanswered anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically a `char` is just not applicable since it only has 256 possibilities for values. In your code you can use `wchar_t` instead of `char`.

I would use [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) and their Internationalization functionality. It supports Unicode and would thus solve your problem. Here's an [example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/tools-i18n.html) showing how to use it for different languages as well. There's also [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) (International Components for Unicode) - look at [this](http://userguide.icu-project.org/intro).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read [this article by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on Unicode and character sets to understand what you are facing.

Then find out what kind of internationalization support your GUI toolkit offers.